# How can I efficiently search stringified data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, database-design

I have a parent `ProductCategory` and child `Product`. For example:

```
ProductCategory --- Product
          Drill --- DeWalt DWD 112
                --- Black & Decker 5 C
        Bicycle --- Motobecane Turino ELITE Disc Brake
                --- Shimano Aluminum
```

For a given `ProductCategory`, there are a set of attributes that all `Products` should be comparable with each other on (i.e., have data on). However, this set of attributes is likely to vary between `ProductCategories`

For example, for the `ProductCategory` of Drill, the attributes might be `Voltage, Amps, Corded vs Cordless`. Every `Product` Drill needs to have such information. However, for the `ProductCategory` of Bicycle, the attributes should be `Size, Road vs Mountain`, and every `Product` bicycle needs to have this information. (Sorry I don't know anything about either drills or bikes... why I picked this was stupid)

I'm trying to design the DB such that for a given `Product`, the attributes are something that I can easily search. For example, ideally I can run this command:

```
drills = Product.where(product_category_id:1)
drills.where("voltage >= ?", 5)
-> returns the individual drills, which may include DeWalt but not Black & Decker
```

This seems to present an interesting trade-off... because then I'd have to have `Product` have columns for every attribute for every `ProductCategory`, even those that aren't relevant to it. For example:

```
# Product columns
:voltage, :integer #for Drill
:amps, :integer #for Drill
:corded, :boolean #for Drill
:size, :integer #for Bicycle
:mountain, :boolean #for Bicycle
...
```

This doesn't seem sustainable... you can see very quickly that for just a few `ProductCategories` there will soon be an infinite number of `Product` columns!

At the other end of the spectrum, I thought about having defining attributes required of each `Product` in the parent `ProductCategory`, and then requesting these attributes/storing them on `Product` as a stringified data:

```
# ProductCategory has a column...
:required_attributes, :text

ProductCategory.where(name:"Drill").first.required_attributes
-> "voltage,amps,corded"

ProductCategory.where(name:"Bicycle").first.required_attributes
-> "size,mountain"

# Product has a column...
:attribute_data, :text

Product.where(name:"DeWalt").first.attribute_data
-> "{'voltage':5,'amps':5,'corded':5}"
```

With the design above, I could create a front end that enforced that, upon `Product` creation, one has to provide information for each `required_attributes` after it's been split based on commas. But of course, this makes searching much less efficient, at least I THINK it does... so this is my question. **How can I efficiently search stringified data?** If I'm searching for all Drills with at least 5 volts, so complete the below.

```
drills = ProductCategory.where(name:"Drill")
drills.where("attribute_data ...")
```

Comment: see the updated answer.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it was not really a good answer. But this not really a question that can be answered on SO as its very broad and requires a bit of knowledge about the existing patterns like EAV tables and JSON columns.

Comment: I get that @max but I find the references therein​ useful I'm exploring this admittedly broad topic. Would you mind reposting, even as a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to use a [JSON or HSTORE](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json) datatype column on `products` to store the specifications.

But if you want to have a bit more control and validations per specification you can use a design with a join table:

```
class Product
  has_many :specs
  has_many :definitions, through: :specs
end

# This is the "normalized" table that defines an specification
# for example "Size". This just holds the name for example and the acceptable values.
class Definition
  has_many :specs
  has_many :products, through: :specs
end

# this contains the actual specs of a product (the value)
# specs.payload is a JSON column
class Spec
  belongs_to :definition
  belongs_to :product
  delegate :name, to: :definition

  def value
    payload[:value]
  end

  def value=(val)
    payload[:value] = val
  end
end
```

One of the classic problems with using a design like this would be that the `specs` table would have to store the value as a text (or varchar) column and deal with the issues of type casting. But most modern DB's support dynamic column types like HSTORE or JSON that you can use to  store the actual value.

The downside is that you have to use a special SQL syntax when querying:

```
Spec.where("payload->>'value' = ?", "foo")
```

This is a sort of normalized variation on what is called the [Entity–attribute–value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) which can be an anti-pattern but is often the only good solution to dynamic attributes in a relational database.

See:

- [ActiveRecord and PostgreSQL](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json)
- [ActiveRecord::ActsAs - Multi Table Inheritance for AR](https://github.com/krautcomputing/active_record-acts_as)

Comment: really helpful. for what i was doing, ended up using JSON datatype, also because i've been wanting to dip into NoSQL for awhile. don't delete either of these answers! will likely want to read later

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach the problem which avoids the issue of EAV tables is to use multi-table inheritance. This example uses ActiveRecord::ActsAs.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  actable
  belongs_to :brand
  validates_numericality_of :universal_product_code, length: 12
  validates_presence_of :model_name, :price
end

class Bicycle < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :product
  validates_numericality_of :gears
  validates_presence_of :size
end 

class PowerTool < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :product
  validates_numericality_of :voltage, :amps
  validates_presence_of :voltage, :amps
end
```

This would store the base information on a `products` table:

```
change_table :products do |t|
  t.decimal :price
  t.sting :model_name
  t.integer :universal_product_code, length: 12
  t.integer :actable_id
  t.string  :actable_type
end
```

And it uses a polymorphic association to store the subtypes of products on more specific tables:

```
create_table :bicycles do |t|
  t.integer :gears
  t.integer :size
end

create_table :power_tools do |t|
  t.boolean :corded
  t.integer :amps
  t.integer :size
end
```

The advantage here is that you have a defined schema instead of a bunch of loose attributes. 
The drawback is if you are designing a generic web shop then a fixed schema will not cut it.